# Roxygen2 introduces \n to default parameter value. Causes Codoc mismatches

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

I'm having the opposite issues of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616088/roxygen-how-to-set-a-default-parameter-inculding-backslash-to-functions). It seems that roxygen is introducing `\n` into my default parameter values which causes R CMD check to WARN

Here's my function definition:

```
WriteToExcel <- function( filePath = stop( "filePath must be specified" ) , worksheet = stop( "worksheet must be specified" ) , toWrite = stop( "toWrite must be specified" ) , rownames = FALSE )
{
 ...
}
```

And here's the warning:

```
Codoc mismatches from documentation object 'WriteToExcel':
WriteToExcel
  Code: function(filePath = stop("filePath must be specified"),
                 worksheet = stop("worksheet must be specified"),
                 toWrite = stop("toWrite must be specified"), rownames
                 = FALSE)
  Docs: function(filePath = stop("filePath must be\n specified"),
                 worksheet = stop("worksheet must be\n specified"),
                 toWrite = stop("toWrite must be specified"), rownames
                 = FALSE)
  Mismatches in argument default values:
    Name: 'filePath' Code: stop("filePath must be specified") Docs: stop("filePath must be\n  specif
ied")
    Name: 'worksheet' Code: stop("worksheet must be specified") Docs: stop("worksheet must be\n  spe
cified")
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: AFAIK, this is a known issue with roxygen2.  This happens when the function arguments gets line-wrapped to fit to a given width.  For time being, I'm just living with the warning.

Comment: ah!  good to know that this is a known issue.  I couldn't find the issues tracker for Roxygen2.  Is there one?

Comment: the known issue: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/21, and the fix is here: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/26 (not accepted yet) At the moment I usually use a dirty hack -- leave the arguments empty, and use `if (missing(my_arg)) {my_arg <- ...}`

Comment: awesome!  I'll use the hack =) Any ETA on when this will be accepted and updated on CRAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a known issue.  Closing out this question.